# Selecting the image after execCommand

Tags: javascript

Have been banging my head against the wall on this one for a while now.

I have an editor that is inserting an image but I can't get it to select the newly inserted image in Firefox after execCommand Runs.  Here's my code.

```
        var editor = this;
        var sel = editor._getSelection();
        var range = editor._createRange(sel);           
        editor._doc.execCommand("insertimage", false, imgURL);
        img = range.startContainer.previousSibling;
        console.log(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use execCommand, use range.insertNode instead.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'http://www.carsyouwilldrive.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/futurecar1.jpg';

var selection = document.defaultView.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
range.insertNode(img);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ogane4/5/edit

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, but this won't work in IE. Also, the (unspecified) editor the OP is using will almost certainly contain an iframe and has its own range and selection API, which may well expose a cross-browser `insertNode()` method.

Comment: @Tim The OP specifically listed Firefox so I figured IE wasn't an issue. I can support it if need be... but more info from the OP is required.